# Microsoft excel color picker is different on different documents

Tags: excel, excel-2013

I have two Excel two documents on the same laptop with an extended desktop. 
For some reason, when i use the color picker, i get different color options on each of the documents. Here are the two options i see:

### Document1.xlsx

[image: Doc1.xlsx]

### Document2.xlsx

[image: Doc2.xlsx]

Does anybody know why the two documents are displaying different colors?
I would like to use the colors shown in **column 9** in the the document 1 colours but i want to use them in document 2. How do i make both documents display the same colours?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They may have two different themes selected. [See this page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/change-a-theme-and-make-it-the-default-in-word-or-excel-c846f997-968e-4daa-b2d4-42bd2afef904) on How to Change a Theme.  But, to the point:

> On the Page Layout tab in Excel or the Design tab in Word, click Colors, and pick the color set you want.